# Reinicio problemático del Progressbar al duplicar el valor de ésta

Tags: c#

Tengo un pequeño programa donde saco fotos y al final del proceso genera un GIF con todas las fotos recopiladas. El tema es que utilizo un progressbar y muestro también un texto con el valor en el que va el progressbar. La cosa de todo esto es, que al acabar el proceso si quiero crear otro mismo proceso, el valor va a x2 en vez de ir 1 a uno, y si vuelvo a realizar otro a x3 y así sucesivamente.
Si es necesario algo de código puedo ponerlo pero era solo por preguntar si es algun tema del progressbar o el timer. (El timer está en un interval de 1000ms.

Adjunto el código:

```
namespace FotoMaton
{
    public partial class FotoMaton : Form
    {
        private static string Path = @"\\C:\Fotos\";
        private bool HayDispositivos, terminado;
        private string nombre;
        private int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0, eleccion;
        private FilterInfoCollection MisDispositivos;
        private VideoCaptureDevice miWebcam;
        private MagickImageCollection gif = new MagickImageCollection();

        public FotoMaton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        private void Creador()
        {
            CreacionGif cg = new CreacionGif(gif, nombre);
            cg.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void MarcaAgua(PictureBox picturebox1)
        {
            Graphics g;
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            RectangleF angulo = new RectangleF(1350, 975, 535, 90); 
            using (g = Graphics.FromImage(picturebox1.Image))
            {
                //g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), 655, 460, 535, 90); 
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                g.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 32,                    FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, angulo, sf);

                EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new                                   EncoderParameters(1);
                ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Encoder myEncoder =  Encoder.Quality;
                EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new                                      EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 30L);
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

                if (progressBar1.Value == 0)
                {
                    j = 0;
                }
                picturebox1.Image.Save(Path + textBoxNombreFoto.Text + "_" + i + ".jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                gif.Add(Path + textBoxNombreFoto.Text + "_" + i + ".jpg");
                gif[j].AnimationDelay = 200;
                j++;
            }
            g.Dispose();
            sf.Dispose();
        }
        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CargaDispositivos();
        }
        public void CargaDispositivos()
        {
            MisDispositivos = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            if (MisDispositivos.Count > 0)
            {
                HayDispositivos = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < MisDispositivos.Count; i++)
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(MisDispositivos[i].Name.ToString());
                comboBox1.Text = MisDispositivos[0].Name.ToString();
            }
            else HayDispositivos = false;
        }
        private void CerrarWebcam()
        {
            if (miWebcam != null && miWebcam.IsRunning)
            {
                miWebcam.SignalToStop();
                miWebcam = null;
            }
        } 
        private void Capturando(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if(terminado == false)
            {
                Bitmap Imagen = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = Imagen;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            CerrarWebcam();
        }
        private void foto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (miWebcam != null && miWebcam.IsRunning && (radioButton1.Checked == true || radioButton2.Checked == true) && textBoxNombreFoto.TextLength > 0)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();
                timer1.Interval = 1000;
                timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                terminado = false;

                if(radioButton1.Checked == true)
                {
                    eleccion = 18;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = 1800;
                }
                else
                {
                    eleccion = 36;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = 3600;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor revisa que todos los campos estén rellenos");
            }
        }
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CerrarWebcam();
            int i = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
            string nombreVideo = MisDispositivos[i].MonikerString;
            miWebcam = new VideoCaptureDevice(nombreVideo);
            miWebcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Capturando);
            miWebcam.Start();
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CerrarWebcam();
            int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            string nombreVideo = MisDispositivos[i].MonikerString;
            miWebcam = new VideoCaptureDevice(nombreVideo);
            miWebcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Capturando);
            miWebcam.Start();
        }
        private void finFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MarcaAgua(pictureBox1);
            terminado = true;
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (progressBar1.Value % 30 == 0 && progressBar1.Value <= eleccion && terminado != true || progressBar1.Value == 0)
            {
                miWebcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Capturando);
                MarcaAgua(pictureBox1);

                z++;
            }
            if (progressBar1.Value < eleccion && terminado == false)
            {
                progressBar1.Value++;
                i++;
            }
            textBoxTiempo.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
            textBoxTiempo.Update();

            if ((terminado == true || progressBar1.Value >= eleccion) &&  i!=0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();

                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                nombre = textBoxNombreFoto.Text;
                Creador();

                i = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Proceso Terminado con Éxito");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo poner el código, así podemos ver dónde está el problema y ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Siempre es conveniente dar una lectura a [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) antes de enviar una pregunta.

Comment: Buenas @Omar , he añadido parte del código donde me da el problema.

Comment: Por favor pon el código completo. [Lee esto (Ejemplo mínimo reproducible)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hecho @GeorgiaFernández

Comment: Hay muchisimo codigo, y creo que veo tu problema, pero para asegurarme, en algun lugar, cuando apagas el timer, le estas quitando el evento tick que le agregaste? igual, no entiendo porque haces eso por codigo.. cuando no es necesario...

Comment: El tick no lo estoy quitando en ningún momento tan sólo hago un timer.stop para pararlo e igualar a 0 la barra de progreso. @gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que el problema esta en la instrucción

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

Esta instrucción se debe ejecutar una única vez, podrías ponerla en el form_load

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era eso lo que estaba provocando el duplicado. Tomo nota de lo que me has comentado y lo pondré siempre en sitios donde se ejecute la instrucción una sola vez.

Comment: @Gorben no es solo eso... si guardas el handler al evento, despues lo podes quitar con -= ;).... por eso te preguntaba si lo habias sacado en algun lado... Igual te vuelve a repetir.. todo eso que haces por codigo en el timer no tiene sentido, se puede hacer directo en el form sin mas problemas y ahorrarte todo... el evento tick se lo das al definir el control

Comment: Te refieres a que ponga en propiedades del timer el intervalo y si está enabled en el mismo diseño? El evento tick lo que estoy haciendo es que cada segundo pase y haga el tema de la foto. Es una forma para que cada segundo lo recorra. Seguramente haya una forma mucho más óptima, pero no se me ocurrió más con mi limitada experiencia